# Using a Wiener Filter to Estimate a Transfer Function

Tags: estimation, transfer-function, correlation, linear-algebra, adaptive-filters

As a follow on [Estimate the Transfer Function of an Unknown System](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15284/estimate-the-transfer-function-of-an-unknown-system) which os estimating a transfer function of an unknown system using a [Wiener](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter) filter,

1. How would you put a minimum [MSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) criteria on how well the estimated filter weights matched the actual transfer function of the system? [Suppose you needed the MSE to be no more than -50dB]?
2. How would you change his [formulation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/15366/5843) if you wanted poles as well as zeroes (an IIR rather than an FIR filter)?

Answer (score 1):

1. The desired MSE is application dependent, so there can be no general
   rule. If the approximation doesn't satisfy your needs you can
   increase the filter length to obtain a better match.
2. There is no straightforward way to change the FIR Wiener filter solution to an IIR solution because the IIR formulation results in a set of nonlinear equations which have no closed-form solution. The IIR solution might also be unstable, so FIR filters are a much more practical choice when computing a Wiener filter.